# Selecting a tab when clicking on list item of another tab

Tags: android

I have three tab (TabA, TabB, TabC), By default TabA selected. In TabC I tooked a list and when user click on list_item (any), I want to show TabA with that data on user clicked. How can I do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `TabHost.setCurrent(int)` on the List's `onItemSelected` event